# Javascript page gets laggy after a few hours when calling a function every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, scope, timeout

I'm refreshing data in my javascript page by calling a function every 10 seconds which requests most recent data from my server.

This is the function that is called every 10 seconds:

```
function loadEvents() {
      //Angular $resource factory
      EventsService.getEvents({}, function(response) {
        var events = response.events;
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        $scope.currentevent = null;
          for(var i = 0; i<events.length && $scope.currentEvent === null; i++){
            var value = events[i];
            if(new Date(value.start).getTime()<now && new Date(value.end).getTime()>now){
              $scope.currentEvent = value;
          }
        }
        //I use daypilot to show the events, the below code only updates the list of events if 
        //The events have changed
        var currentEvents = JSON.stringify($scope.scheduler.events.list);
        var newEvents = JSON.stringify(events);
        if(currentEvents!=newEvents){
          $scope.scheduler.events.list = events;
          $scope.scheduler.update();
        }
        $timeout(function () {
          loadEvents();
        }, 10000);
      });
}
```

For some reason, the page gets laggy after about 5 hours. This is specially noticeable on slow devices like my android tablet. This issue doesn't occur after removing the $timeout. This seems like a memory issue? I can solve the issue by just refreshing the page by calling `location.reload();` every 5 hours, but this doesn't seem the best solution. I rather want to solve the issue that is causing this behavior.

I also measured how long it takes to execute the function and get the response from server, this never takes longer than 100ms. The events returned by the server is only for 1 day and is just a few kilobytes.

Comment: Just an idea, but perhaps the events are accumulating, not being replaced.  It may be that you're calling it properly but some reference to the old events still remain because the library doesn't clear it out as you'd expect.  Have you tried to see if there weren't some sort of "clear" function on scheduler?

Comment: It doesn't seem to accumulate, because when I log the events, the list only contains the most recently requested events. Also there doesn't seem to be a way to clear all events at once, I can only remove one event at a time. See: https://api.daypilot.org/daypilot-scheduler-events-remove/

Comment: My first impression was that the event was triggering multiple times.  Are you sure that timeout is setting a single event and not repeated events?

Comment: Yes, timeout triggers a single event. I also tried $interval, which caused the same lag issue.

Comment: I'd start by using the Profilers in Chrome Development Tools, especially the Record Heap Allocations or Take Heap Snapshot profilers to see if it is indeed a memory issue, and if yes what kind of items accumulate. If no, you can still do CPU profiling which may give you some pointers to what exactly is lagging.

Comment: @user3494179 Set timeout from 10 seconds to 100ms to replicate the problem in a matter of 3 minutes rather than 5 hours.  I wish I could help you further, but at least you'll be able to replicate the problem quicker to solve it.  If you *can't* replicate the problem, then that in of itself will tell you alot.